# Python AsyncIO fails to create a protocol because of missing transport though transport is present

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-asyncio

I am trying to write a proxy server using AsyncIO's asyncio.protocol's and that seems to work for the biggest part. But I am getting an error that confuses me pretty badly.

My code looks the following:

```
import asyncio
import socket

users = {}

class UserConnection(object):
    def __init__(self, client_socket, proxy_socket, peername):
        self.client_socket = client_socket
        self.proxy_socket = proxy_socket
        self.peername = peername

class ClientProxyProtocol(asyncio.Protocol):
    def __init__(self):
        self.transport = None
        self.session = None
        server_connection = loop.create_connection(
                                lambda: ProxyForwardProtocol, 
                                host="127.0.0.1", 
                                port=25575)
        task = loop.create_task(server_connection)
        task.add_done_callback(self.handle_proxy_connection)

    def connection_made(self, transport):
        # Get peername, client socket and create proxy socket
        peername = transport.get_extra_info('peername')
        client_socket = transport.get_extra_info('socket')
        # Get session object for a user and add in dict keyed of proxy socket
        self.session = UserConnection(client_socket, None, peername)
        print('Connection from {}'.format(peername))
        self.transport = transport

    def handle_proxy_connection(self, task):
        trans, proto = task.result()
        proxy_socket = trans.get_extra_info("socket")
        self.session.proxy_socket = proxy_socket
        users[proxy_socket] = self.session
        print(trans,"\n",proto)

    def data_received(self, data):
        message = str(data) 
        print('Data received: {!r}'.format(message))

    def connection_lost(self, exc):        
        print('Close the client socket')
        self.transport.close()


class ProxyForwardProtocol(asyncio.Protocol):
    def __init__(self,transport):
        self.transport = transport

    def connection_made(self, transport):
        proxy_socket = transport.get_extra_info("socket")
        print("HELLO")
        self.transport = transport

    def connection_lost(self, exc):
        print("closing forward connection")
        self.transport.close()

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
# Each client connection will create a new protocol instance
coro = loop.create_server(ClientProxyProtocol, '127.0.0.1', 25565)
server = loop.run_until_complete(coro)

# Serve requests until Ctrl+C is pressed
print('Serving on {}'.format(server.sockets[0].getsockname()))
try:
    loop.run_forever()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass

# Close the server
server.close()
loop.run_until_complete(server.wait_closed())
loop.close()
```

Running this script works perfectly fine to some extent, it accepts new connections and starts up a new Protocol instance, but it produces the following bug after it tries to establish a Protocol Connection with my target server. It produces the following error:

```
Exception in callback ProxyForwardProtocol.connection_made(<_SelectorSoc...e, bufsize=0>>) at .\asyncproto.py:53        
handle: <Handle ProxyForwardProtocol.connection_made(<_SelectorSoc...e, bufsize=0>>) at .\asyncproto.py:53>             
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                        
File "C:\Users\Huhn\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\asyncio\events.py", line 126, in _run                   
self._callback(*self._args)                                                                                         
TypeError: connection_made() missing 1 required positional argument: 'transport'
```

**My question is the following**: The handle shows that the connection_made method takes in a SelectorSocketTransport, which I would assume to be a transport, yet still says it is missing a transport. That makes no sense to me.

I would really appreciate if someone could tell me where my mistake lies since I have not found anyone with a similar problem and am kind of stuck. If i have any kind of architectural misconception about proxies feel free to point them out. I am doing this as a teaching exercise, that is the reason why I am not using third-party alternatives which may lie out there.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you just made a typo in `ClientProxyProtocol.__init__()`.

In `create_connection` first argument must be callable which returns Protocol object, instead your `(lambda: ProxyForwardProtocol)` returns **Protocol class**.

So, when the framework calls `connection_made()`, it will pass a single argument (transport), but the first argument must be `self`. Protocol is a class and not class instance -> method `connection_made()` is not bound -> `self` isn't supplied automatically.

Remove `ProxyForwardProtocol.__init__` method and change your call like that:

```
    server_connection = loop.create_connection(
                            ProxyForwardProtocol, 
                            host="127.0.0.1", 
                            port=25575)
```

Comment: Oh man, you won't believe how thankful I am for that, works exactly as expected. Thank you so so much for this, this will save me a lot headache!